# Is JavaFX a replacement for Java Applets?

Tags: java, applet, javafx

Is [JavaFX technology](http://java.sun.com/javafx/) for building rich internet applications (RIA) a direct replacement for [Java Applets](http://java.sun.com/applets/)?

Comment: what? ask a question of some kind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377593/javafx-is-now-out-are-applets-and-java-desktop-officially-dead-dying answers your question too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, JavaFX is not a replacement for applets. In fact, the idea is that you write applets that use JavaFX to things like what you can do with Adobe Flash or Microsoft Silverlight.

So rather than replace applets, it's expected that JavaFX might make applets popular again.

**edit** (08/15/2019) my answer above is 10 years old - things have changed. Applets are not supported anymore; Oracle does not provide a Java browser plug-in that can run applets with current versions of Java. Don't write code that uses applets anymore.

Comment: +1 -- As a side note, this is one of the main reasons Sun chose to essentially rewrite the Java browser plugin from the ground up. You can learn more about this and JavaFX in general by listening to the May 1 2009 episode of Hanselminutes titled "JavaFX and the Web's Four Virtual Machines." Link: http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=178