# What is the difference between java FX applet and java applet?

Tags: java, javafx

Is java FX applet faster than the traditional java applet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as, I know there is nothing called JavaFX Applet. We just run our JavaFX program in browser by using Applet. In other words, we can export our JavaFX program to the web as an Applet.

Furthermore, JavaFX and Applets are not mutually exclusive, please look [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2008/jw-05-newapplet.html) and [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2008/jw-05-applets.html).

An [SO thread found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377593/javafx-is-now-out-are-applets-and-java-desktop-officially-dead-dying) that might clear the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To add further clarification:

- > An applet must be a subclass of the `java.applet.Applet` class. The Applet class provides the standard interface between the applet and the browser environment. [[1]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html)
- > Swing provides a special subclass of the Applet class called `javax.swing.JApplet`. The JApplet class should be used for all applets that use Swing components to construct their graphical user interfaces (GUIs). [[1]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html)
- You can however embed JavaFX GUI elements inside your Swing-based JApplet, making your applet a [`FXApplet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26689258/3041008)