# JavaFX FXML application as applet

Tags: java, applet, javafx-2, fxml

I have a very simple JavaFX FXML application (an anchor pane with two buttons and a label: one button print a string and the other exit application).

I would like to run this application as applet for testing purpose.

Since I am completely new to this process, can someone help me about how and what to do to deploy my application in a server web space so it can be used by the client side without download the application?

Thanks all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566818/is-it-possible-to-make-javafx-web-applet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in .FXML

```
..xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="DIRECTORY.controler"> //controler.java
```

in .java (Main.java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

    BorderPane pane = null;
    try {
        pane = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(MAIN.class.getResource("FILE.fxml"));
        pane.getStyleClass().add("main");
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(MAIN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 1100, 620));
    primaryStage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(MAIN.class.getResource("FILE.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
    primaryStage.show();


}
```

in .java (controler.java)

```
public class controler implements Initializable {

@FXML
private WebView browser;
@FXML
private Button back, refresh, home;
@FXML
private ComboBox CB;
```

Comment: HI Jackson thank you very much for your help: I get error in controller class: my class is SampleController.java and the error is: DIRECTORY.controller does not exist, same error if I use SampleController

Comment: this "DIRECTORY.controler" is the path where you have to show pro FXML, for example I have my project within the folder entries and the name of my FXML is Form.fxml, then you create a file. java with the same name Form.java

ria is well

.. xmlns: fx = "http://javafx.com/fxml" fx: controller = "cadastros.Form">