# Pass a value to javascript from Java

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have the following Java applet. It gets the absolute file path of a file that a user has selected:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
/*
   <OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
           width=150 height=100 
 codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/jinstall-13-win32.cab#Version=1,3,0,0"> 
     <PARAM NAME="code" value="FileApplet.class">
   </OBJECT>
 */

public class fileabs extends JApplet
{
   private JTextField tfCount;
   final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

  public void init() {
      setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
        p.add(new JLabel("Select File: "));
        tfCount = new JTextField(50);
        tfCount.setEditable(false);
        p.add(tfCount);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Browse...");
        p.add(b2);
        b2.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               tfCount.setText("dsds");
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fileabs.this);
                tfCount.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } );

        // p.add(label);
        add(p);
    }
}
```

However, I need to be able to send this to a form in another language (python/django). How would I grab the value of the abolsute path so I can parse it in javascript? Right now, I don't have access to the path, even if it shows within the applet.

Comment: Javafx provides ways to talk back and forth between javascript on a page and java in an applet.  Check out links found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566818/is-it-possible-to-make-javafx-web-applet) and you will want to look at how it works [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using [LiveConnect](http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/#JAVA_TO_JS), which allows an applet to interact with JavaScript in a page, and vice versa.

The following code calls the global JavaScript function `setPath` in the page with a single argument:

```
netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(appletInstance)
    .call("setPath", new Object[] { path });
```

The applet must be started with the parameter `mayscript` set to either `true` or `mayscript` to be allowed to use LiveConnect.